# Phonegap Geolocation Error: timeout

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, geolocation

I've got the latest phonegap 1.2 and put the test code from the docs in my application. When I run my app both on the simulator (xcode 4.2 simulator 5.0) and on my iPad running 5, I get the error "Geolocation Error: timeout".

Has anyone else experienced this?  Here is my code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        // PhoneGap is ready
        function onDeviceReady() {
        var myOptions = { enableHighAccuracy: true };
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError,myOptions);}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing with the script file importing issue. You need to import `phonegap-1.2.0.js` rather than `phonegap.js`.

following snippet work in iOS 5 simulator and on Device too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Device Properties Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.2.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            // Wait for PhoneGap to load
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            // PhoneGap is ready
            function onDeviceReady() {
                 var myOptions = { enableHighAccuracy: true };
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError,myOptions);
            }
            // onSuccess Geolocation
            function onSuccess(position) {
                var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
                element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '
' +
                'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '
' +
                'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '
' +
                'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '
' +
                'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '
' +
                'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '
' +
                'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '
' +
                'Timestamp: '          + new Date(position.timestamp)          + '
';
            }
            // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
            function onError(error) {
                alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                      'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
            }
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're using PhoneGap Build importing phonegap.js is actually fine: Build embeds the latest stable release both as phonegap.js and phonegap-x.y.z.js.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from iMayur is showing, that the non native geolocation API is working. If you call this script the first time on an iphone, than you will be asked the "geolocation access question" from the browsers HTML5 api.

I think here is a bigger issue in phonegap: [Issuetracker #197](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-iphone/issues/197)

[EDIT]

There is a new issue opened: [Issuetracker #304](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-iphone/issues/304)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if they fixed it for you.
Now assuming that your code is correct:
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError,{'enableHighAccuracy':true,'timeout':10000});
Add the timeout part, and it shouldnt give a timeout error anymore.